# PHP memory_limit in a shared hosting environment

Tags: php, memory, limit, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am on a shared hosting environment and recently I got a memory allocation errors. Then, I checked the PHP in cPanel, and I saw the memory limit is 1024M, but my RAM is only 512M. Then I searched for it and I saw this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/732218/what-is-phps-memory-limit) saying that RAM needs to be greater than PHP memory limit. And said also that, I can use `ini_set()` to manually set the memory limit lower than the RAM.

My questions are:

1. (For second opinion) Should I manually configure the memory limit? lower than the RAM?
2. What is the best `memory_limit` size should I put if the RAM is 512M ?
3. If any case, I configured it successfully, will the allocation memory error vanish?
4. Will this lessen the performance of my website?
5. What will happen to the performance of my website? [Good and Bad]

**UPDATE**

Here I got an error again:

```
 couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for
```

Comment: 512 should be plenty. I would take a look at your script and see why it needs more than 512M of ram.

Comment: What was your memory allocation error? PHP should just swap to disk if there's not enough RAM. I don't think the post you've quoted is correct, you can most likely set it to more than the system RAM.

Comment: If a script needs more then 512mb of ram, you're doing something wrong. Have you diagnosed where this issue occurs instead?

Comment: "I got memory allocation errors" doesn't help much.  What specifically were the errors?  Shared hosting usually implies you don't have your own hard RAM limit, so I don't know what you're referring to with 512MB, I'd be pretty surprised if a server only had 512MB of RAM these days.

Comment: @this.lau_ actually the virtual is the one always hitting it's limit which is 768M, i think when many user's use, the errors is related to `subphp` the error is vanished already.

Comment: @bassxzero yes, I think so too, my website is quite well optimized now.

Comment: @Xorifelse yes, my scripts does not need a **whole** 512M of RAM, can you support your answer as `you can most likely set it to more than the system RAM`? thanks.

Comment: @Devon errors is related to `subphp`, the error is deleted when I visited the cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all (answer to *#1*) PHP memory is located in RAM, so you can't allocate more than your RAM capacity. Keep in mind that 512Mb ram is for all users on site together, not for each request separately.

Second (answer to all other): If you have 512MB PHP limit and it's exceeded, than your scripts are taking too much resources and will slow down/stop your website. Optimize all operations and queries.

Comment: uhm, the default php memory limit that I saw in cPanel is 1024M (set by the hosting providers), and the RAM is 512M. The errors that I get is related to `subphp`, virtual memory.